# Как очистить форму?

Tags: javascript, input, html-form

Есть форма:

```
<input type="text" class="input">
```

Ее надо очистить.
JS:

```
$(".input").text("")
```

Так не работает.
А вот так `$(".input").val("")` работает. Почему?

Comment: потому что `$(".input").text("")` устанавливает `innerText`, выбранных элементов, что для input-элементов не имеет смысла

Answer (score 2):

Потому что `$(".input").val("")` устанавливает значение которое должно быть в `input`. Грубо говоря, у тега `input` есть атрибут `value` и `.val("")` производит запись текста в этот атрибут. А `$(".input").text("")` не может записать значение в атрибут `value` тега `input`, то есть как это не его функция вообще, он для этого не предназначен.